# .NET Packer/Protector

Tags: malware, obfuscation, .net

I have been trying to analyse a .NET trojanized software, here is the link for reference:https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/6186e0b5b1d820744f8f7aa682eec6b043ba11c7737a64e173522b8b55d06f81/detection

[image: file inside DnsPy]

It would be great if someone could help me identify this obfuscation/packing/protection, as I am really not proficient with .NET obfuscation and unpacking. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Regards

Reverse engineering rookie.

Answer (score 1):

Using DetectItEasy you can obtain the Packer used:

"Protector: Crypto Obfuscator For .Net (5.X)"

[image]

de4dot supports this packer, so if you use it `de4dot.exe <filename>` you will obtain the unpacked file

[image]

Bye